# How to pass an environment variable through docker compose and gunicorn?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, gunicorn

I have an restful-api service written in python (using flask and gunicorn in a docker container). Now I want to pass an environment variable through docker compose's 'environment:'.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7
# Set work directory
WORKDIR /API
# Install package we need
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "run_api.sh"]
```

run_api.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /API
gunicorn server:app
```

server.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--port", default=8551, type=int, help="API Port")
    parser.add_argument("--foo")
    parser.add_argument("--bar")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False, port=args.port)
```

I use gunicorn to run my server. After I built the image, I want to use docker compose to deploy the service and pass some variables like `--foo` and `--bar`

How should I fixed this?

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  ts-api-0:
    image: myimage
    container_name: "mycontainer"
    network_mode: "bridge"
    pid: "host"
    ports:
      - "8551:8551"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - "foo=foofoo"
      - "bar=barbar"
```

Briefly speaking, i need to pass variables from `docker-compose.yml`to`gunicorn`to`server.py`.

Much appreciated!!